# Cordova app scrolling on Android

Tags: html, cordova

I'm currently working on an Android app that displays a simple html-document with some css. However, the html changes based on the day, once I've gotten that implemented at least, so there will some days where it will have more elements than it did previously. Now, where the problem lies, is that when there are a many elements, the bottom ones won't show. They are hidden outside the screen, and there is no scrolling.

How would I go about making the page scrollable? This is only for android. I can't use iScroll, seeing that it requires a list-structure in the html, which I don't have and it would be a pain to rewrite the script that makes the html file :/

I posted a similar post yesterday, but I didn't seem to get any responses. Hopefully someone will know a solution today :)

Thanks

Comment: Can you post some code which you want to achieve? because you can detect scroll event with jQuery as well

Comment: I'm really new to this whole mobile app thing, and I don't have an example of some code that would work. I haven't tried using jQuery yet, seeing that I have no experience with it, but if you know how that would be done, please let me know :)

Comment: If your code works in Android Browser (Not Chrome), it will work in your Cordova Application